# Will firestore orderBy work if I use date value?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am storing data like

```
{
date: 23/04/2020,
User: Ganesh
}
```

If I use `orderBy('date','desc')`, will it order it in descending order?

P.S: for now it is working for me but, I want to whether it is really ordering can I believe in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're storing dates as strings like that (dd/mm/yyyy), they will not always sort in date order.  They will always sort in [lexicographic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) string order, which is not the same.

For example, October 1, 2019 will sort after January 1, 2020, even though it's earlier in time, because the initial character "1" is greater than "0".

1. 01/01/2020
2. 10/01/2019

If you need to store a formatted date, I suggest using a format that sorts the way you expect, by putting the largest units first, and the smallest units last, such as "yyyymmdd".

1. 20191001
2. 20200101

Comment: But, can I completely depend on it? Or should I have to use timestamp (some blogs were using this term)? I am beginner so worried.

Comment: Where would this go wrong? I wouldn't be recommending it of I didn't think it would work. You oy need timestamps if you need to store a moment I. Time, not a day of the year.

Comment: Thanks sir! I am implementing it now.